# Is there a way to hide namespaces from the Error List in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to set up Visual Studio 2010 to not display the namespace in the Error List/Output window?  Its actually more of a hindrance than a help.  Most of the time, I know what namespace a class is in just by the name, and if I don't I, I can find out easily by jumping to the code.  So is there a way?

Comment: I doubt it... I haven't seen such a feature. These things are reported with their full and complete name so that it is possible to disambiguate between two classes with the same name in two different namespaces.

Comment: @CodyGray, I know why they do it.  I'm just saying it becomes a nuisance when one's namespace hierarchy becomes 6 or 7 levels deep.  Most of the exception is just the namespaces.

Comment: This is going to sound a bit snarky, but have you considered that the problem might be a namespace hierarchy that is 6 or 7 levels deep? I can't imagine why you'd really need such a deep hierarchy. In my mind, namespaces have two primary functions: to group related functionality and to solve name clashes. A couple of levels usually serves well enough.

Comment: @CodyGray, a bit snarky yes, but I was expecting it.  My organization is fairly rigorous.  It follows as [Organization/Project].[Application].[ApplicationComponent].[Component Type (Views, Models, ModuleDefs etc...)].[Module].  6 or 7 was an exaggeration, but even with these it is cumbersome.  I'm also not going to refacter my enter application to resolve this annoyance.  Also, the namespace is not just in my code, it is used all throughout my design to identify components.  Mine is a rather complex system.  Namespaces simplify its organization.